# C#: "Swedish" characters in Xpath when parsing Lating1Encoded docs

Tags: c#, xpath, latin1, file-encodings

I've a set of html docs that I need to parse. They are encoded in Latin1Encoded. I'm using HtmlAgiliy pack for "parsing".

I have a Xpath query (with swedish characters) that I can't get to work because of different encodings between the docs and the encoding VS stores the XPath query in??

Xpath query:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//h2[text()='Företag']/../div//span[text()='Resultat:']/../div");
```

The xpath query works fine in the Firefox extension xpath checker.

Comment: How does the data that you want to parse look like?

Comment: I had a case of "magic", It suddenly started to work, which is both great and irritating.... I read somewhere that VS starts to store in UTF8 first when needed?

Comment: The format VS stores your source file should not matter because strings in the C# are always in Unicode at runtime (http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html). If your input XML document has been loaded correctly then both XPath expression and XML are in Unicode encoding internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you provide more sample code and some input XML document? From the information given I wrote a little sample program which just works as expected. Does the following work for you?

**Sample document:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<doc>
  <test>Företag</test>
  <test>Hallå</test>
</doc>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XPathDocument xpdoc = new XPathDocument(@"sample.xml");
        XPathNavigator nav = xpdoc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathNodeIterator iter = nav.Select("//*[text() = 'Företag']");

        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(iter.Current.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Företag
```

From the sample code given it seems that you are using the [`Microsoft.Windows.Design.Documents.Trees.DocumentNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.windows.design.documents.trees.documentnode.aspx) class. However, the documentation states that this class is not intended to be used directly. May I ask what you are trying to do?

Update: It might be that you are facing an issue with whitespace normalization (which might be done by your FireFox add-in and not in your code). Have you tried to change your XPath by replacing the test `text() = 'Företag'` by `normalize-space() = 'Företag'` (Just to exclude the case that there is additional leading or trailing whitespace)?